# Random freezes on 20.04 with Dell XPS 9310

Tags: 20.04, dell, xps

I have a Dell XPS 9310 with 20.04 installed from the factory. Everything is working mostly fine, except that my computer freezes every now and then (about once a day). Most of the time, this happens when the screen is locked, though I have observed this while I am using the computer as well. How can I debug this issue? (I have already run memtest, and it found no memory errors.)

Comment: Have you tried Dell's customer support? If this computer is still under warranty Dell should fix it.

Comment: I am having the same issue with my brand new Dell XPS. I will be contacting dell tomorrow to discuss debugging it. I have found the freezing/crashing is only happening during wake up, on light load, and when browsing chrome. when I am playing games it works better than expected.

Comment: @Sean I managed to solve my issue, and posted an answer below. Hope it is useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, I managed to fix my problem by upgrading the kernel version. I installed the package `linux-oem-20.04-edge` and chose the most recent kernel when booting the system. `uname -s` now tells me that I am running the version 5.10.0-1008-oem. I haven't experienced any freezes in about a month now.

Comment: Same same, OEM kernel 5.6 was buggy and was freezing frequently, updating to latest HWE kernel 5.8 fixed this problem for me..